# Ruby string scan returns different results for different string

Tags: ruby, string, tokenize

```
irb(main):161:0>  "Ready for your my next session?".scan(/[A-Za-z]+|\d+|. /)
=> ["Ready", "for", "your", "my", "next", "session"]
=> ["Ready", "for", "your", "my", "next", "session", "?"] #==> EXPECTED
irb(main):162:0> "yo mr. menon how are you? call at 9 a.m. \"okay\"".scan(/[A-Za-z]+|\d+|. /)
=> ["yo", "mr", ". ", "menon", "how", "are", "you", "? ", "call", "at", "9", "a", "m", ". ", "okay"]
=> ["yo", "mr", ". ", "menon", "how", "are", "you", "? ", "call", "at", "9", "a",".", "m", ".", "``", "okay", "''"] #==> EXPECTED
```

I am trying to use this `scan(/[A-Za-z]+|\d+|. /)` to tokenize the string and even the punctuations, even if there is an escaped quote in the string, `\"`

But it is behaving differently on different structure of a string? How to correct?

Comment: “Expected: `"\`\`", "okay", "''"`”—are you kidding? There is no way `Regexp#scan` will transform double typewriter quotes into what you expect.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ to match punctuation, regular expression engines have a dedicated matcher: [`\p{Punct}`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties).

Comment: @mudasobwa I wont be joking if I know ;) If not transform then how to correct the output to proper tokens?

Comment: The 3rd alternative in your regex `. ` matches any character followed by a space. That's why your output contains `"? "` and `". "` but not `"?"` or `"."` or `"\""`.

Comment: I am a little lost with regexes! If now I do `(/[A-Za-z]+|\d+|.| /)`, the returned array will have spaces in addition to the missing punct the way you pointed - `["Ready", " ", "for", " ", "your", " ", "my", " ", "next", " ", "session", "?"]`

Comment: @arjun do you want spaces? if not then don't include them. right now the trailing space is an implied literal matcher e.g. `/ /` is an implied literal space identical to `/\s/` which is an explicit literal space. if you don't want spaces then make sure there are no spaces in your regex

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /
    (?:          # begin a non-capture group
      \"?        # optionally (?) match a double-quote
      \p{alpha}+ # match one or more letters
      \"?        # optionally (?) match a double-quote
    )            # end non-capture group
    |            # or
    \d+          # match one or more digits
    |            # or
    [.,?!:;]     # match a punctuation mark
    /x           # free-spacing regex definition mode

"yo mr. menon how are you? call at 9 a.m. \"okay\"".scan(r)
   #=> ["yo", "mr", ".", "menon", "how", "are", "you", "?", "call", "at", "9",
   #    "a", ".", "m", ".", "\"okay\""]
puts "\"okay\""
   # "okay"
```

The regular expression is conventionally written

```
/(?:\"?\p{alpha}+\"?)|\d+|[.,?!:;]/
```